# LoadControl in static/shared function

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, dynamic-controls

Anyone know how I can dynamically load a control inside of a shared/static function?  The function itself is inside of a mustinherit/abstract class.  (It's an ASP.NET project in VB) I want to do something like this:
VB:

```
    Public Shared Function GetWidget(ByVal name As WidgetName) As Control
        Select Case name
            Case WidgetName.Name1
                Return LoadControl("~/Control1.ascx")
            Case WidgetName.Name2
                Return LoadControl("~/Control2.ascx")
            Case WidgetName.Name3
                Return LoadControl("~/Control3.ascx")
        End Select
    End Function
```

my C# is a little rusty, so this might have some syntax errors:

```
Public Static Control GetWidget(WidgetName name)  
{  
    switch (name)  
    {  
        Case WidgetName.Name1:  
            return LoadControl("~/Control1.ascx");  
            break;  
        Case WidgetName.Name2:  
            return LoadControl("~/Control2.ascx");  
            break;  
        Case WidgetName.Name3:  
            return LoadControl("~/Control3.ascx");  
            break;  
    }  
}
```

(Where WidgetName is an enumerator.)

I'm getting "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.", but I don't understand this error.  I understand what it means, I just don't understand why calling LoadControl isn't seen by the compiler as being an explicit instance of the class. What's not explicit about using LoadControl to create a new control from a file?  I tried creating a new user control and initializing it, then setting it to a different control with LoadControl to no avail.  I also don't want to do a DirectCast because I'm trying to put this in a shared, mustinheret (abstract) class, which therefore doesn't have an .aspx file to write in a `<%@ Reference Control="~/SomeControlPath.ascx" %>`, so the class name is unavailable.

What I'm trying to do is write a static function that takes some value and returns a control based only on that control's source file location.  The end result is a user-modifiable list of controls.  They get a column of controls that they freely add, remove, or reorder based on a static list of available child controls that I specify.  I'm not married to this approach; it might be really wrong in more ways than one.

yeah, I know the static strings being there is code smell, it doesn't actually look like that; it's a simplification for the sake of asking the question.

C#, VB, or plain English explanations all welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because LoadControl can't be returned from your class? Can you try this instead...

```
    Protected Static string GetWidget(WidgetName name)  
    {  
        switch (name)  
        {  
            Case WidgetName.Name1:  
                return "~/Control1.ascx";  
                break;  
            Case WidgetName.Name2:  
                return "~/Control2.ascx";  
                break;  
            Case WidgetName.Name3:  
                return"~/Control3.ascx";  
                break;  
      }  
 }
```

and call the method like

```
... = LoadControl(GetWidget(name));
```

<strike>I suspect that the other alternative is to cast the control</strike>

```
Control c;
...
Case ...
   c = (ControlName)LoadControl("~/Control1/.ascx");
   break;
...
return c;
```

However the calling code would still need to cast it back to its type...

Comment: It is not about what is getting returned...it is that you cannot call the LoadControl method from inside the static method...because there is no instance.

Comment: No worries, been there! Grab a coffee and stay off the beer :) :)

Comment: @CSharpAtl - You are correct which is why I suggested an alternative.

Comment: @Rippo...your casting solution will not work...because you cannot call `LoadControl()` from inside the static method.

Comment: haha I didn't drink last night, I've just been going at it for a few hours non-stop on a very finicky project I inherited, so I'm a little frazzled ;)

Answer (score 11):

Actually, you can do it like this (it works):

```
UserControl tmp0 = new UserControl();
Control ctl = tmp0.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
```

Answer (score 1):

`LoadControl` is an instance method on the `TemplateControl` class which the `Page` class inherits from, and you do not have an instance of the `Page` class inside your `static` method (there is no `this` object because it is a static method).

Comment: ah, thank you for the technicals, that's helpful to know.  I understand the error now.  Up until now I hadn't really thought much about the context of the LoadControl definition, I just took it for granted and used it.

Comment: In your intellisense menu...`LoadControl` should not have come up as an option in your static method..

Comment: yeah, it doesn't.  I wrote the body of the method with the signature specifying it as an instance method, then decided it would be an easier read if it was shared so I changed the signature, which is when I started to see the error and didn't quite understand it.

Answer (score 1):

All good information here, but I'm surprised that no one has used it to make the leap to an actual solution to the original question:

```
Public Shared Function GetWidget(ByVal name As WidgetName,
                                 ByVal onTemplate As TemplateControl) As Control
    Select Case name
        Case WidgetName.Name1
            Return onTemplate.LoadControl("~/Control1.ascx")
        Case WidgetName.Name2
            Return onTemplate.LoadControl("~/Control2.ascx")
        Case WidgetName.Name3
            Return onTemplate.LoadControl("~/Control3.ascx")
    End Select
End Function
```

I tested this solution and it woks.

I like it better than Rippo's solution because it prevents the caller from having to worry about the LoadControl details.  And this is definitely a better solution if there is more work to be done to the resulting control other than simply returning it.

I would not have reached this solution without CSharpAtl's answer, though, because I (stupidly) did not realize that LoadControl is a method on TemplateControl.  Like the original poster, I was very confused about why I was getting the same error.  I could not understand why it would not be OK to load a control in a shared method, and in fact, it is OK if you know how to call LoadControl in this context!

Brian